# Nested functions in F#

Tags: function, f#

I have a simple function that lists every prime factor of a given input number. It is composed by:

```
let rec f n x a = 
    if x = n then
        x::a
    elif n % x = 0 then 
        f (n/x) x (x::a)
    else
        f n (x+1) a

let fact n = f n 2 []

fact 315
val factors : int list = [7; 5; 3; 3]
```

It works, but I would like to make of it a single function: how can I define `fact` with `f` directly nested in? I tried to apply the concept brilliantly expressed [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/organizing-functions/), but I fail to abstract how to nest a three argument function (`f`) in a one arguments one (`fact`).

Comment: `fun` can not be used as an identifier in F#, as it is a very common keyword.

Comment: This does not even compile. First, `fun` is a keyword. Second, where do `f` and `a` come from?

Comment: `f` is probably the same thing as `fun`.

Comment: And I suppose `a` should be `q`.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev that's what I thought at first, but it results in different outputs: [-1; -105; 3]. And it takes a while to compute. :P

Comment: I posted the raw version of the problem I was trying to adapt, now it should be more straightforward. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Move the function body of `fact` to a new line. Make sure that it's indented.
2. Add a blank line between the declaration of `fact` and the function body you just moved.
3. *Cut* the entire definition of `fun`, and *paste* it into the blank line you created in the second step.
4. Indent the copied code so that it become a local function of `fact.`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is move the recursive function `f` to within `fact`, and then call it. It will use the parameters passed to `fact`:

```
let fact n =
    let rec f n x a = 
        if x = n then
            x::a
        elif n % x = 0 then 
            f (n/x) x (x::a)
        else
            f n (x+1) a
    f n 2 []

fact 315
//val it : int list = [7; 5; 3; 3]
```